# limit of integrals of sequence of continuous functions with pointwise convergence to another continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

For $n \geq 1$, let $f_n : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function s.t. $f_n \to f$ pointwise and s.t. $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Assume further that $\{f_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is uniformly bounded on $[a,b]$. Show that:
$$ 
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^bf_n(x) dx = \int_a^b f(x)dx
$$
What I tried was to show was $|\int_a^bf_n(x)-f(x)dx| \leq \int_a^b|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx \to 0$. As $[a,b]$ is compact I tried to write $[a,b] \subseteq \bigcup_{j \in J} B_\delta(x_j)$ for $J$ finite s.t. $|f_n(x_j)-f(x_j)| < \epsilon$ for all $j \in J$ and $n \geq N_1$.

Then I tried to do something like $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < |f_n(x)-f_n(x_k)| + |f_n(x_k)-f(x_k)| + |f(x_k)-f(x)| < 3\epsilon$ or something for all $x$, but then I realized this is me trying to show uniform continuity which was not guaranteed. Specifically I cannot say that $|f_n(x)-f_n(x_k)| < \epsilon$ because of circular dependency.

How should I approach the problem instead?

Edit: To clarify, this is the Riemann integral and I would prefer proofs that rely on elementary methods (no DCT), thanks!

Comment: There is an elementary proof (i.e. not using measure theory) [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2317801) for the more general case where $f_n,f$ are only assumed to be Riemann integrable, but I guess one can find shorter proofs under this additional stronger assumption that they are continuous.

Comment: Thanks, I think this proof here answers the question nicely. I'm still open to answers that perhaps simplifies things using the extra assumption of continuity.